# How do i preserve the state of a control inside gridview with paging in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, paging

I Have added the validation of a TextBox inside this GridView, but this validation is only working on the current page of the GridView (it is not working on the previous and next pages of the GridView).

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grd1" runat ="server" Width ="100%" AllowPaging ="true" pagesize="5">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="NM" ItemStyle-Width="300px" HeaderStyle-Width="300px" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size (GB)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSize" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function IsValidateAdd() {
        if (validateGridTextBox() == false)
            { return false; }
    }

    function validateGridTextBox() {
        var flag = false;
        var dropdowns = new Array(); //Create array to hold all the dropdown lists.
        var gridview = document.getElementById('<%=Grd1.ClientID %>'); //grvDMODetails is the id of ur gridview.

        dropdowns = gridview.getElementsByTagName('input'); //Get all dropdown lists contained in Grd1.            
        for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            if (dropdowns.item(i).value != "") //If dropdown has no selected value
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == false) 
        {
            alert('Please enter Table Size.');
            return flag;
        }

</script>
```

Code behind:

```
btnAddDM.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return IsValidateAdd();");
```

Comment: where is your validation control markup in it

Comment: It might be client side validation

Comment: So when the page is posted back, because that's the scenario you're speaking of, do you see the "onclick" rendered in the outputted HTML?

Comment: before save the gridview data actually i want to do the validation the textbox should have values in all the pages of a gridview

Comment: Your "validateGridTextBox" function is missing a closing bracket.  I don't know if that's causing you any trouble, but it's not good =)

Answer (score 0):

when you navigation thru prev page or next page,the grid view part has changed,but the javascript function was binded to the original grid view.this is why it does not work.

If you want it work,there are 2 solutions

1,when you navigation to other pages,bind the javascript validate function again manually.

2,add onclientclick attribute to the textbox control,such as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSize" runat="server" Width="100px" onClientClick="validateGridTextBox(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

and change your validateGridTextBox javascript function accordingly.